# C - character array initialization

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct, initialization

How does the initialization happen in cases 2, 3, 4, 5 below. 1 will contain garbage.

```
char x[16];
char x[16] = {0};
char x[16] = {0, };
char x[16] = {1};
char x[16] = {1, };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the brace initializer syntax with arrays, any additional elements not mentioned in the initializer list are initialized with zeros.

Comment: Note that C++ allows "char c[16] = {};" to fill everything with zeros.

Answer (score 4):

@Philipp is correct.

A quick test gave me this:

http://codepad.org/DsOtXIYg

btw that's a great link for running test code.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. This should be a comment. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: I did not have 50 rep to add a comment to someone else's post, but now I have :)